# How to show Lottie file in container background at flutter

Tags: flutter, lottie

Now showing Lottie file like this.

```
      Container(
             width: 400,
             child: Lottie.asset("assets/lotties/GamePlanAnimation.json")
        );
```

Now I need to show the Lottie file as the background

Comment: do you mean background of container or all page? Could you clarify it

Comment: You can use Stack to add Lottie at the lower layer and upper layer you can just use Row and Column to make a layout

Comment: Use Stack widget

Comment: Thank you guys, it's Completed using Stack

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a container, I used a Positioned widget inside of the Stack widget to adjust different aspects of the Lottie animation. Here is my code sample:

```
Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          left: -200,
          top: -200,
          height: 400,
          width: 400,
          child: Opacity(
            opacity: 0.4,
            child: LottieBuilder.asset(
              "lib/assets/animations/login-rotation.json",
              reverse: true,
              options: LottieOptions(enableApplyingOpacityToLayers: true),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),],);
```

Answer (score -1):

first of all of my solution that i have use as create a separate class which you set your image as a background of your app screen

```
class BackgroundWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final childView;

  BackgroundWidget({required this.childView});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, //set as like you want
          image: AssetImage(
            'assets/background.png',
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: ClipRRect(
        // make sure we apply clip it properly
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
            child: childView,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

then you use this widget class anywhere as you can like this.

```
MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Color(0xff18728a),
  ),
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('Dashboard'),
      brightness: Brightness.dark,
    ),
    body: SafeArea(
      child: BackgroundWidget(
        // here is your widget class for background
        childView: Container(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use Stack:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      width:double.infinity,
      height:double.infinity,
      child: Lottie.asset('assets/lottieFile.json'),
    ),

    // --
    // You can insert your content or code in here
    // --

  ]
)
```